# Python TKinter Checkbutton Half States

Tags: python, tkinter

I notice that when clicking the unchecked checkbox, the box switches over to a "half-state," before flipping to a fully checked.  It looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?  Checking / unchecking takes longer than it should because of this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import randint
from Tkinter import *

# Set up main window settings
master = Tk()
master.title ("Window")
master.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)

def femaleOption():
    maleCheckbox.deselect()

def maleOption():
    femaleCheckbox.deselect()

#Create female checkbox
femaleIsChecked = IntVar()
femaleCheckbox = Checkbutton(master, text = "Female", command = femaleOption, variable = femaleIsChecked)
femaleCheckbox.select()

#Create male checkbox
maleCheckbox = Checkbutton(master, text = "Male", command = maleOption)

femaleCheckbox.pack()
maleCheckbox.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What platform are you on? are there other checkboxes tied to the same `IntVar`? just having one checkbox I cannot reproduce on my mac, if there is more code needed to get that state [please include it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I am on Mac.  I will update this post with more code shortly.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I reduced my code to what is needed for the example.  I'm new to Python, normally a C++ guy, so this is out of my comfort zone and I totally expect that I have done some things incorrectly.

Comment: This code works fine on my mac, and I don't see anything unusual about the code. It works exactly as I expect it to.

Comment: Weird, the tristate pops up every time I go from unchecked to checked.  I wonder what could be causing this issue.

Comment: @BryanOakley what OS version are you running?

Comment: I am running OSX Sierra version 10.12..6

Comment: Strange, same here, on a 2015 Retina MacBook Pro.  I have no idea why it's performing different for others.

Answer (score 4):

This "half state" represents the `tristate` value. Depending on how you configure this, you'll usually see this when the value of the associated variable is the empty string. That is because the default `tristatevalue` is the empty string.

From the canonical [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm):

> If a checkbutton is selected then the indicator is normally drawn with a selected appearance, and a Tcl variable associated with the checkbutton is set to a particular value (normally 1). The indicator is drawn with a check mark inside. If the checkbutton is not selected, then the indicator is drawn with a deselected appearance, and the associated variable is set to a different value (typically 0). The indicator is drawn without a check mark inside. In the special case where the variable (if specified) has a value that matches the tristatevalue, the indicator is drawn with a tri-state appearance and is in the tri-state mode indicating mixed or multiple values.

What this means is that somewhere in your code you're likely setting the variable to an empty string, either explicitly or implicitly.

The way to prevent this is to make sure that the associated variables are properly defined (ie: not local variables), and that they are always set to either the `onvalue` (default 1) or `offvalue` (default 0).